# How to convert ARKit Depth data (CVPixelBuffer) to 16-bit grayscale PNG image file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, arkit, grayscale

According to [Apple's official example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/converting_color_images_to_grayscale), I made some attempts. This is my codes:

[CGImage extension](https://github.com/CocoaDebug/stackoverflow/blob/main/UIImage%2Bext.swift)

```
//ARSessionDelegate
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    let depthMap = frame.sceneDepth.depthMap
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthMap)
    let cgImage = CIContext().createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
    let grayscaleCGImage = cgImage.toGrayscale() //CGImage extension
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: grayscaleCGImage)
    let data = image.pngData()
    
    //Save data to iPhone as "example.png" PNG file...
    //Get "example.png" PNG file from iPhone, copy PNG file to MacOS...
}
```

Then in MacOS terminal, I run this codes `sips -g all example.png`, I get the following information from terminal:

```
  pixelWidth: 256
  pixelHeight: 192
  typeIdentifier: public.png
  format: png
  formatOptions: default
  dpiWidth: 72.000
  dpiHeight: 72.000
  samplesPerPixel: 1
  bitsPerSample: 8
  hasAlpha: no
  space: Gray
```

The `bitsPerSample`  is `8`, But I want it to be `16`. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!